# Compressor drain

Tags: drain, valve, compressor

Whenever I drain my compressor only some droplets come out and I find that strange so today I opened the drain valve and I tried tilting the compressor and brownish/orange water came out, the compressor is a stanley one bought it in November (its new). Is this normal, should I always have to tilt my compressor to drain the water?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the drain isn't at the bottom of the tank, then yes it's normal and yes you should tilt the compressor to correct that before blowing out the water.

Comment: The compressor is an horizontal one, the drain is like at the middle, maybe it is not leveled with the floor and the water is like going to the back of the compressor?

Comment: ...so level it until the drain works without fiddling with it.

Comment: I will try leveling it to see if that works, thank you, you think there is any reason to worry about rust yet since there has been water in the tank for some time?